# Bluetooth Visibility Crashes UI on Linux Mint

Tags: drivers, configuration, bluetooth, crash

I'm running a Lenovo laptop.  I have had driver problems for a while now, and am planning to perform a re-install of Linux Mint when I have the time and I can make sure that it won't interfere with my college courses.  This is the output of the command "uname -a":

Linux $NAME 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have omitted the actual name of my computer for privacy reasons.  Before I started having this issue, I wanted to turn off my bluetooth connection at startup, as it would automaticaly turn on, and I did not want this on by default.  I edited the bluetooth configuration file as specified in this post:

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1102

I think that I may have messed with a few too many configuration options, so here is a print dump of the file '/etc/bluetooth/main.conf':

```
[General]

# List of plugins that should not be loaded on bluetoothd startup
#DisablePlugins = network,input

# Default adaper name
# %h - substituted for hostname
# %d - substituted for adapter id
Name = %h-%d

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
# considered.
Class = 0x000100

# How long to stay in discoverable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 180, i.e. 3 minutes.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay discoverable forever
DiscoverableTimeout = 180

# How long to stay in pairable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 0.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay pairable forever
PairableTimeout = 0

# Use some other page timeout than the controller default one
# which is 16384 (10 seconds).
PageTimeout = 8192

# Automatic connection for bonded devices driven by platform/user events.
# If a platform plugin uses this mechanism, automatic connections will be
# enabled during the interval defined below. Initially, this feature
# intends to be used to establish connections to ATT channels.
AutoConnectTimeout = 60

# What value should be assumed for the adapter Powered property when
# SetProperty(Powered, ...) hasn't been called yet. Defaults to true
InitiallyPowered = false

# Remember the previously stored Powered state when initializing adapters
RememberPowered = false

# Use vendor id source (assigner), vendor, product and version information for
# DID profile support. The values are separated by ":" and assigner, VID, PID
# and version.
# Possible vendor id source values: bluetooth, usb (defaults to usb)
#DeviceID = bluetooth:1234:5678:abcd

# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. This option is really only needed for qualification since the BITE tester
# doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases (though there could in
# theory be other useful purposes for this too). Defaults to true.
ReverseServiceDiscovery = true

# Enable name resolving after inquiry. Set it to 'false' if you don't need
# remote devices name and want shorter discovery cycle. Defaults to 'true'.
NameResolving = true

# Enable runtime persistency of debug link keys. Default is false which
# makes debug link keys valid only for the duration of the connection
# that they were created for.
DebugKeys = false

# Enable the GATT functionality. Default is false
EnableGatt = false
```

Comment: Please edit to add `lsusb; rfkill list all; lsmod | grep blue` thanks